# Не понимаю, как работает coroutine и как организовать асинхронность в lua

Tags: lua

Согласно документации, coroutine должна запускать подпрограмму в отдельном потоке, но это этого не происходит:

```
function test()
    while true do
        --nothing
    end
end

co = coroutine.create(test)

print("STARTED")
coroutine.resume(co)
print("FINISHED")
```

Я ожидаю получить на выводе строки "STARTED" и "FINISHED", а получаю только "STARTED"! Функция test, запущенная через coroutine, продолжает блокировать общий поток.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coroutine - это сопрограмма, а не поток, о чём в док-ции написано. Они работают в одном потоке, и передают друг другу управление самостоятельно. Небольшой пример:

```
function test(...)
    print(...)
    print(coroutine.yield('First return'))
    return 'Second (real) retrn'
end
co = coroutine.create(test)
print("STARTED")
print(coroutine.resume(co, 'Argument to first call')) 
print(coroutine.resume(co, 'Argument to second call'))
print("FINISHED")
```

Он печатает

```
STARTED
Argument to first call
true    First return
Argument to second call
true    Second (real) retrn
FINISHED
```

Comment: А существует ли способ запустить функцию в отдельном потоке, подобно тому, как это реализовано в javascript? Я пишу простой udp-сервер для небольшой love-игры и мне не хотелось бы возиться с тяжёлыми фреймворками, просто нужно как-то обрабатывать сессии для каждого соединения параллельно.

Comment: В вашем случае я рекоммендую посмотреть в сторону copas - он как раз подходит для ваших целей, хотя работает в одном потоке. А если нужна полноценная многопоточность - без сторонней библиотеки (их много) не обойтись.